# Display requestbin data on my webpage index

Tags: php, curl, iot

I connected my sensor device on requestbin, now this requestbin is working and accepting and display the data. Now I want to display the data in my index.php website

Here is the requestbin url : https://requestbin.co/r/enbh3gv751la/1E9GvdfMpWVS2U789k0AWXp5UeA

As you will see, it is accepting data. But I dont know how to call this data in my index.php.

All I know is how to send a request:

```
<?php
$handle = curl_init('https://enbh3gv751la.x.pipedream.net/');
$data = [
  'key'=>'value'
];
$encodedData = json_encode($data);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encodedData);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
$result = curl_exec($handle);
?>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I work on the pipedream team that operates this bin service. Currently there's not a way to extract requests sent to a pipedream endpoint, but I'd love to learn more about your use case.

For example, would you prefer to pull data via an API, or would a model where we pushed you events via a webhook (for example) be ideal? Are you trying to display the data on a website, or ingest it into some data store for further analysis?

[Emailing our Support alias](https://pipedream.com/docs/support/) will be the best way to get help, and we can discuss these details and anything else you might need from there.